# Notification click already open application not reopen in android

Tags: android, xml, push-notification

more than one activity use in application click song notification already open application not reopen application how to solve this error

```
  Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.setAction(Control.ACTION.MAIN_ACTION);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

   <activity
        android:name=".Activity.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize" />
```

and i have declare android:launchMode="singleTop" all activity in android manifest file

Answer (score 0):

> android:launchMode="singleTop"

It means if the activity is already there on the top, it won't create an another instance. Instead `onNewIntent()` of an `activity` will get called *with updated intent* as a parameter.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    // Deal with new Intent over here...
}
```